# CSS website layout adaptive to content

Tags: html, css, layout, height

I cannot manage to get the wrapper to expand with it's content...

Here is the structure:

```
 * {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}  
body {
background-color: #ccc;
background-repeat:repeat;
font: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
}
.wrapper {
width: 95%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
/* ------------------------ Start Header -----------------*/
.header {
background-color: #333;
}
* html .header {height:110px} /* IE Min-Height Hack */ 
/* ------------------------ End Header -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Nav Bar -----------------*/
.nav-bar {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
margin: 0px 0px 13px 0px;
min-height: 17px;
padding: 13px;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
}
* html .nav-bar {height: 17px} /* IE Min-Height Hack */ 

.nav-links li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin-right: 16px;
font: normal small-caps normal 12px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.nav-links li a:link {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li a:visited {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li a:hover {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #999;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* ------------------------ End Nav Bar -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start outer content -----------------*/
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#outercontent {
background-color: #e8e8e8;
width: 97,5%;
padding: 13px;
min-height: 655px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;

  background-color: orange;
  /*padding-bottom: 100em;*/
  /*margin-bottom: -500em;*/
}
* html #outercontent {height: 655px} /* IE Min-Height Hack */ 
/* ------------------------ End outer content -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Columns -----------------*/
#centercolumn { /* Parent Wrapper for inside boxes background-color:    #333333; */ 
background-color: #333333;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
display: inline; /* IE Hack */
padding: 7px;
width: 80%;
min-height: 630px;
float: left; 

  background-color: red;
 /* padding-bottom: 250em; */
 /* margin-bottom: -250em; */

}

.p {
font: normal small-caps normal 40px/1.2 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

table.db-table-products { border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px   solid #ccc; background-color:#FFF; overflow:hidden;}
table.db-table-products th  { padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc;   border-top:1px solid #ccc; font: normal small-caps normal 12px/1.2 Tahoma,   Geneva, sans-serif, bold; background-color: #FFF; color: #000;}
table.db-table-products td  { padding:4px; border-left:1px solid #ccc;   font: normal small-caps normal 10px/1.2 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; border-  top:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#999;}

table.db-table-products caption { 
font: normal small-caps normal 16px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
display: table-caption;

}

table.db-table-products hr { 
display: block;
margin-top: 0.5em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 1px;
}

/* unvisited link */
table.db-table-products a:link {
color: #FFDD38;
}

/* visited link */
table.db-table-products a:visited {
color: #D8C150;
}

/* mouse over link */
table.db-table-products a:hover {
color: #D8B70F;
}

/* selected link */
table.db-table-products a:active {
color: #D8B70F;
}

.rightcolumn {
margin: 0px 0px 13px 13px;
padding: 7px;
display: inline; /* IE Hack */
width: 210px;
min-height: 160px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
background-color: #ccc;
font: normal normal 10px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666666;
}
/* ------------------------ End Columns -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Footer -----------------*/
#footer {
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
padding: 15px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
background-color: #e8e8e8;
font: normal normal 10px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666666;

   background-color: blue;
 /* padding-bottom: 100em; */
 /* margin-bottom: -200em; */
}
/* ------------------------ End Footer -----------------*/

h1 {
font-size: 23px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight:bold;
font: normal small-caps normal 23px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}
.float {
float: left;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
img {
border: none;
}
/* Links */
a:link {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #333333;
background-color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here it is HTML code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <!-- <link href="table-css/table-db.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main4.css" />
 <title>Products Market</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
 <!-- Start Wrapper -->
 <div class="wrapper">
 <!-- Start Header -->
 <div class="header"> <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="1200" height="150" /> 
 </div>
 <!-- End Header -->
 <!-- Start Navigation Bar -->
 <div class="nav-bar">
 <ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">24h Monetary Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Actual Monetary Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Jobs Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
 <!-- Start Outer Content -->

 <div id="outercontent">
 <div id="centercolumn">
  <h1><b><u>Welcome</u></b></h1>
  <p>  
 <?php include 'test.php'; ?>
 </p><br />
 </div>  

 <!-- Start Right Content -->
 <div class="rightcolumn">
  <h1><u><b>About Me</b></u></h1>
  TEXT </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
  <h1><u><b>Search</b></u></h1> 
    </div>
    <br />
    </div>

  <!-- End Right Content -->
  </div>

  <!-- End Outer Content -->
  <!-- End Outer Content -->
  <!-- Start Footer -->
  <div id="footer"> &copy; Copyright with <a href="http://www.code-sucks.com/">Code-Sucks.com</a> 2006-2015 </div>
  <!-- End Footer -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Wrapper -->
  </div>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

I would like that outer part of layout reach the same height of content?

Here we go with the solution to the problem. It's a little bit different from the one suggested by petebolduc, but his idea helped me to find a mix solution.

So this is the code:

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body {
background-color: #ccc;
background-repeat:repeat;
font: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
}
/* ------------------------ Start Header -----------------*/
.header {
background-color: #333;
}
* html .header {height:110px} /* IE Min-Height Hack */ 
/* ------------------------ End Header -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Nav Bar -----------------*/
.nav-bar {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
margin: 0px 0px 13px 0px;
min-height: 17px;
padding: 13px;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
}
* html .nav-bar {height: 17px} /* IE Min-Height Hack */ 

.nav-links li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin-right: 16px;
font: normal small-caps normal 12px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.nav-links li a:link {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li a:visited {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li a:hover {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #999;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* ------------------------ End Nav Bar -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start outer content -----------------*/
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
vertical-align:top;
width: 95%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#outercontent {
background-color: #e8e8e8;
width: 97.85%;
padding: 13px;
/* min-height: 655px;*/
margin-bottom: 13px;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
/* height:auto;*/
/* position:relative;*/
/*text-align:left;*/
vertical-align:top;

/*      background-color: orange; */
  /*padding-bottom: 100em;*/
  /*margin-bottom: -500em;*/
}
/** html #outercontent {height: 655px;} */
/* ------------------------ End outer content -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Columns -----------------*/
.lefthalf_col {
width:79.5%;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
left:0;
top:0;
vertical-align:top;
}

.righthalf_col {
width:19.2%;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
/*  right:0;*/
left:.9%;
vertical-align:top;
}
#centercolumn { /* Parent Wrapper for inside boxes background-color:  #333333; */ 
background-color: #333333;
/* margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/

padding: 7px;
width:100%;
min-height: 630px;
height:auto;
position:relative;
top:0;

/* width: 75%;*/
/* min-height: 630px;*/
display: inline-block; /* IE Hack */
/* top:0;*/
/* float: left; */

/*      background-color: red; */
 /* padding-bottom: 250em; */
 /* margin-bottom: -250em; */
}
.rightcolumn {
margin: 0px 0px 13px 13px;
padding: 7px;
/* display: inline-block; /* IE Hack */*/
/* width: 210px;*/
width:100%;
min-height: 160px;

position:relative;
top:0;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
background-color: #ccc;
font: normal normal 10px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666666;
}

.p {
font: normal small-caps normal 40px/1.2 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}


table.db-table-products { border-right:1px solid #ccc; border- bottom:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#FFF; overflow:hidden;}
table.db-table-products th  { padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc;  border-top:1px solid #ccc; font: normal small-caps normal 12px/1.2 Tahoma,  Geneva, sans-serif, bold; background-color: #FFF; color: #000;}
table.db-table-products td  { padding:4px; border-left:1px solid #ccc;  font: normal small-caps normal 10px/1.2 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; border- top:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#999;}

table.db-table-products caption { 
font: normal small-caps normal 16px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
display: table-caption;

}

table.db-table-products hr { 
display: block;
margin-top: 0.5em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 1px;
}

/* unvisited link */
table.db-table-products a:link {
color: #FFDD38;
}

/* visited link */
table.db-table-products a:visited {
color: #D8C150;
}

/* mouse over link */
table.db-table-products a:hover {
color: #D8B70F;
}

/* selected link */
table.db-table-products a:active {
color: #D8B70F;
}
/* ------------------------ End Columns -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Footer -----------------*/
#footer {
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
padding: 15px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
background-color: #e8e8e8;
font: normal normal 10px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666666;

 /* background-color: blue; */
 /* padding-bottom: 100em; */
 /* margin-bottom: -200em; */
}
/* ------------------------ End Footer -----------------*/

h1 {
font-size: 23px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight:bold;
font: normal small-caps normal 23px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}
.float {
float: left;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
img {
border: none;
}
/* Links */
a:link {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #333333;
background-color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

And here is the html code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main7.css" />
   <title>Products Market</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="container">
   <!-- Start Wrapper -->
   <div class="wrapper">
   <!-- Start Header -->
   <div class="header"> <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="100%" height="150" /> 
   </div>
   <!-- End Header -->
   <!-- Start Navigation Bar -->
   <div class="nav-bar">
   <ul class="nav-links">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">24h Monetary Market</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Actual Monetary Market</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Products Market</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Jobs Market</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
   <!-- Start Outer Content --> 
   <!--  <div class="tablegraph">
   <div class="row"> -->
   <div id="outercontent">
   <div class="lefthalf_col">
   <div id="centercolumn">
   <h1><b><u>Welcome</u></b></h1>
   <p>  
   <?php // include 'query.php';
   include 'query2.php'; ?>  ‫
   </p><br />
   </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Start Right Content -->
   <div class="righthalf_col">
   <div class="rightcolumn">
   <h1><u><b>About Me</b></u></h1>
   TEST
   </div>
   <div class="rightcolumn">
   <h1><u><b>Search</b></u></h1>
   <br />
   TEST
   </div> 
   </div> <!-- half_col -->


   <!-- End Right Content -->
   </div>
   <!-- End Outer Content -->
   </div>

   <!-- Start Footer -->
   <div id="footer"><p> &copy; Copyright with <a href="http://www.code-sucks.com/" target="_blank">Code-Sucks.com</a> 2006-2015 </p>
   <p>Thanks to <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Stackoverflow.com</a> guys! </p>

   </div>
   <!-- End Footer -->

   </div>
   <!-- End Outer Content -->
   </div>
   <!-- End Wrapper -->
   <!--</div>
   </div>-->

   </body>
   </html>
```

In the end problem seemed to be with "float" attribute.
Changing that and positioning the DIVs I needed for content into wrapper DIV part and into outer content DIV part, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Agree with @PraveenKumar... by your question you acknowledge there is available research but would prefer to have the code written for you. This is a great site with many who are willing to help those who make serious attempts to help themselves first.

Comment: Just to be complitely honest that might seem, if you don't check anything I've written before. Otherwise you would have seen that even if i'm not a programmer in couple of month I've learned to make cross domain json interrogation, automatic cron jobs with database update and so on. this without knowing a single word of js and php.

Comment: The reason Why my question seems so easy to you it's because all the css tutorial (i've found) seems to just jump from very lower level to upper levels. So if you want I can delete the code and simply mantain the question, so i'll do the homework that you say, i don't want to do. In any other case, thx for your time and attention anyway.

Comment: to those who were looking for good tutorial, as I was, there's one here:

http://www.subcide.com/articles/creating-a-css-layout-from-scratch/P1/

Comment: anyway I've tried with:
1) java code, but it didn't worked;
2) padding & margin bottom high values, but it didn't work.

what i don't know is how to make the outer content (that is behind central colum) being as high as central content.. keep on trying.

Comment: I understand the frustrations of being self-taught. I provided an answer for you below.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to your code...

## CSS

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}  
body {
background-color: #ccc;
background-repeat:repeat;
font: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
}
.wrapper {
width: 95%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
/* ------------------------ Start Header -----------------*/
.header {
background-color: #333;
}
* html .header {height:110px} /* IE Min-Height Hack */ 
/* ------------------------ End Header -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Nav Bar -----------------*/
.nav-bar {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
margin: 0px 0px 13px 0px;
min-height: 17px;
padding: 13px;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
}
* html .nav-bar {height: 17px} /* IE Min-Height Hack */ 

.nav-links li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
margin-right: 16px;
font: normal small-caps normal 12px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.nav-links li a:link {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li a:visited {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #333;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li a:hover {
background-color: #E8E8E8;
color: #999;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* ------------------------ End Nav Bar -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start outer content -----------------*/
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  clear:both;
}

#outercontent {
background-color: orange;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 655px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
clear:both;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* ------------------------ End outer content -----------------*/

/* ------------------------ Start Columns -----------------*/
#centercolumn { /* Parent Wrapper for inside boxes background-color:    #333333; */ 
background-color: red;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px;
width: 80%;
min-height: 630px;
float: left; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}
I
.rightcolumn {
padding: 10px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 20%;
float: left;
font: normal normal 10px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666666;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rightcolumn-block {
padding: 7px;
min-height: 160px;
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
background-color: #ccc;
font: normal normal 10px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666666;
}

.p {
font: normal small-caps normal 40px/1.2 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

table.db-table-products { border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px   solid #ccc; background-color:#FFF; overflow:hidden;}
table.db-table-products th  { padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc;   border-top:1px solid #ccc; font: normal small-caps normal 12px/1.2 Tahoma,   Geneva, sans-serif, bold; background-color: #FFF; color: #000;}
table.db-table-products td  { padding:4px; border-left:1px solid #ccc;   font: normal small-caps normal 10px/1.2 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; border-  top:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#999;}

table.db-table-products caption { 
font: normal small-caps normal 16px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
display: table-caption;

}

table.db-table-products hr { 
display: block;
margin-top: 0.5em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 1px;
}

/* unvisited link */
table.db-table-products a:link {
color: #FFDD38;
}

/* visited link */
table.db-table-products a:visited {
color: #D8C150;
}

/* mouse over link */
table.db-table-products a:hover {
color: #D8B70F;
}

/* selected link */
table.db-table-products a:active {
color: #D8B70F;
}


/* ------------------------ End Columns -----------------*/
/* ------------------------ Start Footer -----------------*/
#footer {
border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;
padding: 15px;
margin-bottom: 13px;
background-color: #e8e8e8;
font: normal normal 10px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #666666;

   background-color: blue;
 /* padding-bottom: 100em; */
 /* margin-bottom: -200em; */
}
/* ------------------------ End Footer -----------------*/

h1 {
font-size: 23px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight:bold;
font: normal small-caps normal 23px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}

h2 {
font-size: 23px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight:bold;
font: normal small-caps normal 23px/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
}



.float {
float: left;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
img {
border: none;
}
/* Links */
a:link {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
color: #333333;
background-color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <!-- <link href="table-css/table-db.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main4.css" />
 <title>Products Market</title>
 </head>
<body>

 <div id="container">
 <!-- Start Wrapper -->
 <div class="wrapper">
 <!-- Start Header -->
 <div class="header"> <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="1200" height="150" /> 
 </div>
 <!-- End Header -->
 <!-- Start Navigation Bar -->
 <div class="nav-bar">
 <ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">24h Monetary Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Actual Monetary Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Jobs Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
 <!-- Start Outer Content -->

 <div id="outercontent">
     <div id="centercolumn">
          <h1><b><u>Welcome</u></b></h1>
          <p>  
         <?php include 'test.php'; ?>
         </p><br />
     </div>  

     <!-- Start Right Content -->
     <div class="rightcolumn">

          <div class="rightcolumn-block">
              <h2><u><b>About Me</b></u></h2>
              TEXT 
          </div>

          <div class="rightcolumn-block">
              <h2><u><b>Search</b></u></h2> 
              TEXT
          </div>

     </div> <!-- End Right Content -->


  </div>

  <!-- End Outer Content -->
  <!-- End Outer Content -->
  <!-- Start Footer -->
  <div id="footer"> &copy; Copyright with <a href="http://www.code-sucks.com/">Code-Sucks.com</a> 2006-2015 </div>
  <!-- End Footer -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Wrapper -->
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

## CHANGES

1] I simply copied the same css for `h1` and made css for `h2`. The reason for this is you should only have 1 `h1` tag on your page and it should be the title of the page. I used the same css but you can change as desired.

2] You had two right columns the way your code was written. I rewrote the `rightcolumn` to be a wrap and added a `.rightcolum-block` to hold each of the blocks you wanted inside of `.rightcolumn`. This allows you to work with the columns separate from the content in the sidebar.

3] Look at the CSS for `#outercontent` you will see `clear:both;` This forces the `#outercontent` to stretch with the content contained within. Also you will see `box-sizing: border-box;` This was also added to `centercolumn` and `rightcolumn`. This forces the padding, borders, and margins to be include in the set width of the element instead of adding the setting of each to be added to the element.

4] I remove the width from `#outercontent`. There was no need for this setting.

5] You had a width percentage set on `centercolumn` and a pixel width setting on `rightcolumn`. It needs to be one or the other. Percentages are better for your application so I changed the  width of `rightcolumn` to 20 percent.

I hope this helps... take the time to compare your code and mine to see the changes. If you do not understand something type css and the attribute into google. http://www.w3schools.com/ is usually first and provides easy to understand description of the property/attribute.

Comment: First of all thx a lot for your answer.
I'm gonna test these changes asap.

I've tried clear:both; code but it didn't worked before.
Probably I've missed something else. I'll post the code once it will work.

Again thx.

Comment: you are more than welcome... if you have any questions just ask